# Use of different tenses to express present fact on past action

Tags: tenses

I am trying to write a recommendation letter. The following two sentences sound quite awkward. Is it correct? I mean what I am doing describing all the events on the past tense and on that base I am implying some attribute of the present (this is the only sentence in present tense).

> He frequently interacted with teachers and colleagues on the subject and he demonstrated insight on what he studied. Also he possesses an excellent communication skill.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you shouldn't start a sentence with *also* in a formal context.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic here.

Comment: See [this handy diagram](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another/21847#21847).

Comment: Fine, except that most linguists recognize only two tenses in English, present and past.

Comment: To actually answer your question, there is nothing at all wrong with your use of tenses; it's the other aspects of your letter that bother me. I don't like the phrase "on what he studied". It sounds too much like a form letter. If you're writing a recommendation for him, shouldn't you **know** what he studied?

Comment: -1 I feel like this is a proof-reading question. Discuss topic [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/are-what-is-a-better-way-to-write-this-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the sentences you have written in the past tense. The use of present tense isn't wrong either, but an improved version of that sentence could be:

*What is more, he was able to handle numerous occasions with excellent communication skills.*

I thought of the verb **demonstrate**, which collocates with **skills**, but I didn't like the repetition.

Comment: The phrase "able to handle occasions" is not meaningful and contributes to verbosity.  Perhaps say "His communication skills were excellent" instead.  Or, if *occasions* and numerous other multisyllabic words are wanted, "His communication skills exhibited to excellent advantage on many occasions".

Answer (score 1):

Consider rephrasing as follows:

> He frequently interacted with teachers and colleagues on the subject and he demonstrated insight on what he studied. *He also frequently demonstrated excellent communication skills.*

Using the word **demonstrated** (or synonyms of the word) allows the reader to make the connection that since he had excellent communication skills while you knew him he has excellent communication skills now.

Note: The word *frequently* isn't needed but some adverb would improve the quality of the sentence as it would provide more information about how or when he demonstrated excellent communication skills.

Comment: Is the word *frequently* really necessary there ?

Comment: Good point, it isn't. It is more descriptive though. I'll make note of that.

Comment: Even I have a doubt on this usage - *demonstrated insight*. Can insight be demonstrated ?

Comment: *Demonstrating insight* would be the same as to demonstrating wisdom or demonstrating the ability to process knowledge well. It is a legitimate sentence and does make sense. It does, however, sound like a filler sentence because it's so vague  and doesn't really say anything significant. No employer will say, *"Oh wow! He demonstrates insight? That's incredible! I can't remember that last time someone demonstrated insight."*